# Remove a certain part in a text file

Tags: grep, sed, awk, xubuntu

I got the file, text.txt. In this file I have written:

```
"test"
"okay"
```

I want to remove the `"` part of this file, how'd I do this?

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. Is this what you want: `sed 's/"//g' file` ??

Comment: @glennjackman this is the probable answer, as such it should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

sed, awk, others, many could do this.
tr one:

```
tr -d '"' < file
```

The -d option is to delete things.
And tr doesn't just read files, so use < to feed file content to it. It's same as:

```
cat file | tr -d '"'
```

Comment: I used tr before, but many people have not. Could you add some more details as to why it works?

Comment: Updated. @Hennes